# mongodb collection is not loaded into hive table

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hive

I am currently trying to **migrate** **mongodb collection** into **hdfs** by using **hive**.

I succeeded in creating the mongodb-based hive table and it is present in my hdfs directory when i browse the hdfs UI.

However only the table is showing but the table **is empty**, **no data is available**.

It seems like the mongodb collection is not loaded into the table. below is how I create the table.

```
create table mongo(
id String,
age String,
gender String,
race String,
custState String,
purchaseDate String,
purchaseTime String,
foodname String,
restaurant String,
foodtype String,
quantity String,
totalPrice String,
orderType String,
rating String,
servingType String,
characteristic String,
restaurantType String,
restaurantState String,
priceRange String,
paymentMethod String,
tableBooking String,
onlineBooking String,
deliveryService String)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
STORED BY 'com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.MongoStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES('mongo.columns.mapping'='{
"id":"_id",
"age":"age",
"gender":"gender",
"race":"race",
"custState":"custState ",
"purchaseDate":"purchaseDate",
"purchaseTime":"purchaseTime",
"foodname":"foodname",
"restaurant":"restaurant",
"foodtype":"foodtype",
"quantity":"quantity",
"totalPrice":"totalPrice",
"orderType":"orderType",
"rating":"rating",
"servingType":"servingType",
"characteristic":"characteristic",
"restaurantType":"restaurantType",
"restaurantState":"restaurantState",
"priceRange":"priceRange",
"paymentMethod":"paymentMethod",
"tableBooking":"tableBooking",
"onlineBooking":"onlineBooking",
"deliveryService":"deliveryService"}')
TBLPROPERTIES('mongo.uri'='mongodb://master:27017/bigdatadb.datasetv1');
```

before creating the table I also added jars as suggested tho I am not properly sure what's the significance of it.

```
add jar /usr/local/hadoop/lib/hive-serde-1.0.jar;
add jar /usr/local/hadoop/lib/mongo-hadoop-core-1.5.2.jar;
add jar /usr/local/hadoop/lib/mongo-hadoop-hive-1.5.2.jar;
add jar /usr/local/hadoop/lib/mongo-java-driver-3.8.1.jar;
add jar /usr/local/Hive-JSON-Serde/json-serde/target/json-serde-1.3.9-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar;
```

I am using hadoop 2.9.1, mongodb 4.0.4, and hive 2.3.3. Can anybody help me to fix this issue?

Comment: just to confirm, you are not getting any error, do you ?

Comment: Yes, didn't get any error